# Blockexplorer.com API POST error

Tags: development, api, blockexplorer

I'm trying to write Python code which utilises the (Insight) [Blockexplorer.com API](https://blockexplorer.com/api) , particularly the `POST` functions. I'm testing using the iOS REST app, *[Restler](http://appcrawlr.com/ios/restler)* (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zKBa.jpg)).

The call I'm trying to make is fine when I use *GET* (https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/api/addrs/2NF2baYuJAkCKo5onjUKEPdARQkZ6SYyKd5,2NAre8sX2povnjy4aeiHKeEh97Qhn97tB1f/txs), however for `POST`, I'm having problems. I use `"addrs" = "2NF2baYuJAkCKo5onjUKEPdARQkZ6SYyKd5,2NAre8sX2povnjy4aeiHKeEh97Qhn97tB1f"` as my params (and have tried using dumped JSON, ie`"{ "2NF2baYuJAkCKo5onjUKEPdARQkZ6SYyKd5,2NAre8sX2povnjy4aeiHKeEh97Qhn97tB1f" }"`, but I'm always getting the following error message:

> Invalid addrs param:Cannot call method 'split' of undefined. Code:1

It's clearly a parameters issue, so what gives? (FWIW I'm *not* versed in JavaScript)

---

Relevant screenshot of *Restler* (L) and API documentation (R):

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the POST working. The error you're getting back seems to indicate the key "addrs" is not in the POST payload. Just a guess, but maybe you don't need the quotes and spaces around the payload?

Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: [Very close!](http://m.imgur.com/OjBDrMe). It was the spaces between the `=` causing the issue. The payload must be a string without any spaces, ie, `addrs=2NF2baYuJAkCKo5onjUKEPdARQkZ6SYyKd5,2NAre8sX2povnjy4aeiHKeEh97Qhn97tB1f`